# snapshot.data.data() is null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('user')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .get();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.data.data() == null)
              return Center(child: Text((snapshot.data.data()).toString()));
            else
              return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data.data()['email']),
                    );
                  });
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
            return Text("No data");
          } else
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code is always showing 'null' . What is the reason for which snapshot.data.data() is null?
Im new to future builder and Im not understanding what could be the reason for this error.

Comment: Maybe because `collection('user').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)` does not exist... try `print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid) ` and check if that uid exist in the **users collection**

Comment: @ibrahimxcool uid exists... please give me some other suggestion, should that id be collection uid or documents ID

Comment: Maybe collection name is **users** and not **user**

Comment: try to initialize the value in initState and pass it to Future builder

Comment: @Madhan Can you explain a bit, im new to this concept

Comment: Why are you using the tag 'flutter-web'? Are you trying to run this on the web? If so, we need more data, such as your index.html file. And regardless, post a picture of your collection in firebase. It might be a spelling mistake.

Comment: Hello @Helixxxx the best way to debug is to add a "print(snapshot.data)" in the builder to see the data you get

Comment: @Helixxxx can you try this out ? https://ghostbin.co/paste/4erzjns

Answer (score 0):

just use `snapshot.data==null` or `!snapshot.exists`